# Getting zero width and height of view?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, ipod

I have a main view and inside that I have drag and drop another view which is named firstview.

I am getting zero width and height of view like the below exmple.

```
NSLog(@"  WIDTH =%d",firstview.frame.size.width);
NSLog(@"  HEIGHT =%d",firstview.frame.size.height);
```

What may be the reason?

Comment: have you connected IBoutlet of firstview ?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @waheeda, I guess you have not connected IBOutlet of firstview.

Answer (score 0):

you have drag and drop another view.. so there may be problem of view connect in interface builder

Comment: I have already connected to Interface Builder,though getting problem.